# Jqgrid, call URL with parameters for Json return

Tags: jqgrid

i have the following code on my aspx page:

```
jQuery("#listFondos").jqGrid({
    url: '/PorMyController/LoadGridData/',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames: ['col1', 'col2',...etc
```

Everything is working fine, but i'm wondering if is it possible to call the URL method sending some parameters. I know that by default, when you call the url method, jqgrid sends some parameters to control paging of the grid:

```
public ActionResult LoadGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
```

So, i want to add an extra parameter to make some filter on the data that is going to be loaded into the grid. For example i would like to have this:

```
public ActionResult LoadGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, string filterId)
```

As i know, i don't need to specify the first 3 parameters, cause jqgrid does it by default, but how do i send the filterId parameter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solve the problem myself.
All that is needed to do is send the parameter as querystring on the url:

```
url: '/PorMyController/LoadGridData?filterId=123',...etc
```

The defaul parameters for paging will keep being sended, so you only have to specify the additional parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a function instead of a named datatype for the datatype parameter.  Then in that function you can manually do a jQuery .ajax call with whatever parameters you want.  This thread has a good example:  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727502/how-do-i-get-jqgrid-to-work-using-asp-net-json-on-the-backend).  (Specifically the last answer).