# Passing Query String to Web Service in JavaScript (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, jqgrid, query-string

I'm using jqGrid in ASP.Net, I'm calling a Web Service to fill the grid, my problem is: I want to pass Query String to 'url' property of the grid to the Web Service, how do I that...?
All what I want to do is pass a value to the Service in any way...

My jqGrid Code:

```
function Btt_Search_onclick() {
        SearchFilters = "1"; // Concatenate SearchFilters with , between each filter
        $("#MyGrid").setGridParam({
            url: "../Webservice/QueueManagement.asmx?" + SearchFilters + "/AllDataReport"
        }).trigger("reloadGrid");
    }
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1861900/237808) SO question/answer answers your question.

Basically, you just need to set a query string parameter and have a corresponding parameter in your service.  Based on how you formatted your sample code, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, though.  Couldn't you do something like this:

```
url: "../Webservice/QueueManagement.asmx?filter=" + SearchFilters + "&queueName=AllDataReport"
```