# Lambda Expression "Contains"

Tags: .net, lambda, dynamic-linq

I use a dynamic filter, that filters a collection using object properties, operators and values. Now, if the property is a string, the operator is "contains" and the value is "word", the filtered objects containing the "world" should be filtered accordingly.

In Linq I have the Expression.`Equal`, `NotEqual`, `GreaterThanOrEqual`, `LessThanOrEqual`

but don't have "`Contains`". How to replace it?

Consider the following code (in VB.NET, but does not matter)

```
  Select Case compOp
    Case ComparisonOperator.Contains
      ' ?????? WHAT HERE ???? '
      filterExpression = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of PropertyType, Boolean))(Expression.Equal(myObjPropertyParam, myConstExpression), myObjParam)

    Case ComparisonOperator.Different
      filterExpression = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of PropertyType, Boolean))(Expression.NotEqual(myObjPropertyParam, myConstExpression), myObjParam)

    Case ComparisonOperator.Equal
      filterExpression = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of PropertyType, Boolean))(Expression.Equal(myObjPropertyParam, myConstExpression), myObjParam)

    Case ComparisonOperator.GreatherThanOrEqual
      filterExpression = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of PropertyType, Boolean))(Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(myObjPropertyParam, myConstExpression), myObjParam)

    Case ComparisonOperator.LessThanOrEqual
      filterExpression = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of PropertyType, Boolean))(Expression.LessThanOrEqual(myObjPropertyParam, myConstExpression), myObjParam)
  End Select
```

EDIT:

Used Solution, gratie to Thomas Levesque and  Jon Skeet )

```
  Dim expr As Expression = Nothing

  Select Case compOp
    Case ComparisonOperator.Contains
      expr = Expression.Call(myObjPropertyParam, "Contains", Nothing, constantExpression)
    Case ComparisonOperator.Different
      expr = Expression.NotEqual(myObjPropertyParam, constantExpression)
    Case ComparisonOperator.Equal
      expr = Expression.Equal(myObjPropertyParam, constantExpression)
    Case ComparisonOperator.GreatherThanOrEqual
      expr = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(myObjPropertyParam, constantExpression)
    Case ComparisonOperator.LessThanOrEqual
      expr = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(myObjPropertyParam, constantExpression)
  End Select

  filterExpression = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of PropertyType, Boolean))(expr, myObjParam)
```

Comment: What does 'Contains' mean? Tell us how you would write it in VB first.

Comment: @Gabe: "Contains" should mean like LIKE in SQL or like string Contains() in .NET. say, "Microsoft Word".Contains("Microsoft")

Comment: `Contains` isn't a comparision operator. Its a function call.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: While it returns a True or Flase for 2 members, I name it "comparisonOperator" )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `Contains` operator (although there are *methods* named `Contains`). It would only make sense for some types (like String, collections and a few others), but not for others; for instance how would you define the `Contains` operator for integers or dates ?

Now, if you want to apply the `Contains` method to a string via a lambda expression, you have to generate an expression that calls the method, using [Expression.Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341086.aspx).

Comment: effectivement... But I should build such expressions however, at least for string peroperties

Comment: @serhio: It's not clear what you mean - but it's not hard to use Expression.Call, and as it happens I gave an example of using it today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193974/how-do-i-nest-a-call-to-a-method-within-a-call-to-a-method-using-expression-call/7194171#7194171

Comment: @Jon: I use a dynamic filter, that filters a collection using object properties, operators and values. Now, if the property is a string, the operator is "contains" and the value is "word", the filtered objects containg the "world" should be filtered accordingly. 

I suppose, besides Call I should use something like Evaluate, in order to obtain a boolean value from the lambda expression

Comment: @serhio: Well you'll still need Expression.Lambda, but just with Expression.Call. By the way, as each case of your select uses Expression.Lambda, why not pull that into a single call afterwards? Make the Select just work out the expression that needs to be used with Expression.Lambda.

Comment: @Jon: This select builds a single expression. I have a grid, where each row is an expression. That expressions are combined with OR or AND. So, that expression is returned to an  other function that combines them into a final expression... that is finally applied to a collection.

Comment: @serhio: I don't understand how that relates to my previous comment. Have a separate local variable which is assigned in the Select/Case, and then set `filterExpression` using `Expression.Lambda` after the Select/Case.

Comment: I added a solution according to your suggestions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thomas, @jon-skeet: what about NotContains()? Can I invert the Contains result?

Comment: @serhio, use `Expression.Not` around `Expression.Call`