# Access Server Side DataTable to javascript in asp.net MVC 3.0

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can I access the DataTable created server side in mvc 3.0 in javascript. I want the data  in jqgrid so i need the DataTable in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define WebMethod on you asp.net page and return data in json format.
The question was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727502/how-do-i-get-jqgrid-to-work-using-asp-net-json-on-the-backend) on SO.