# Is there any jquery plugin which act like gridview of asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins

I want to use a plug-in like ASP.NET grid view which is easy.It should be easy to use with web method in web service. Also there must be facility to edit with popup window,deleting rows, paging and search. Can anyone help me out this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this page with [15 examples](http://www.hotscripts.com/blog/15-javascript-data-grids-enhance-html-tables/), don't know if they all are for free. Like Simplybj wrote you can use DataTables (I'm using it in ASP with AJAX calls), and for me (my project) it's quite enought

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [datatables](http://datatables.net/) is a good solution, although I've never used it with ASP.NET. It is flexible and CDN hosted (on the MS AJAX CDN).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php). It can be easly used with HttpHandler or WebMethods (take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727502/how-do-i-get-jqgrid-to-work-using-asp-net-json-on-the-backend) or [here](http://codeasp.net/articles/asp-net/229/using-jqgrid-with-asp-net))