# Is there some good javascript grid that can be filled using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need a grid that can be filled using ajax.

I need to sort, filter and select.

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations

Comment: @bnkdev Related almost to the point of duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The ext grid is rather full featured

http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/#sample-3

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) - it has all of the features you need and more :)

Comment: Though jqGrid isn't free, mind you (at least not the CRUD-enhanced version)

Comment: The JavaScript version is 100% free. Now, if you want the PHP or ASP.NET server-side enhanced versions, that will cost you...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php) is probably your best bet.  If you are wanting to be able to intercept the data before passing to the grid, that's pretty easily done too.  by setting datatype to a function, you can manipulate the loading however you like, then push tlo the grid via addJSONData() when you are done frobbing.

If you have some more specific questions, I'd suggest expanding a bit.  Also, it looks like you might want to check existing questions and answers here.

Comment: Apparently there are issues with addJSONData - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545714/jqgrid-addjsondata-asp-net-2-0-ws - Have you had success using this method?

Comment: yeah, it's kind of lame, the grid attaches to the html element itself, so you need to dereference it...  $("#mygridtable")[0].addJSONData(deserializedObject)  .. the question you refer to, it looks like he processed the object, then was trying to objectInstance.replace() on it, instead of looping through any values he wanted to adjust for.

Comment: @Justin, but the short answer is, yeah, I've been using it in a recent version without issue.

Answer (score 0):

The dojox grid is also a good option: [Documentation here](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the YUI library.